# Twilio video duration and/or endTime within the npm pakage

Tags: npm, video, twilio

It appears that I can not set duration or endTime when creating a room via twilio

My code looks like this

```
client.video.rooms
    .create({
        type: 'group-small',
        mediaRegion: mediaRegion,
        endTime: endDate,
        duration: 500,
        uniqueName: name,
        statusCallback: '',
        maxParticipants: 23
    })
```

I have tried setting both duration and mediaRegion togeather and speratly but it looks like it does not get set and the response from this call has them both set to null all the time.

I just noticed that neither of these params are listed in the interface in the npm code.
So I guess this is why they are not being set. Does anyone know how I can set these or is this a bug in the npm module?

```
interface RoomListInstanceCreateOptions {
  enableTurn?: boolean;
  maxParticipants?: number;
  mediaRegion?: string;
  recordParticipantsOnConnect?: boolean;
  statusCallback?: string;
  statusCallbackMethod?: string;
  type?: RoomRoomType;
  uniqueName?: string;
  videoCodecs?: RoomVideoCodec | RoomVideoCodec[];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

`duration` and `endTime` are not supported parameters when creating a Video Room via the API. You can see the supported parameters in [the Room documentation under Supported POST parameters](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/api/rooms-resource#post-list-resource).

They are:

- `enableTurn`
- `type`
- `uniqueName`
- `statusCallback`
- `statusCallbackMethod`
- `maxParticipants`
- `recordParticipantsOnConnect`
- `videoCodecs`
- `mediaRegion`
- `recordingRules`

If you want to control when a video room ends, you need to do so within your own application.

Comment: but they are listed in the example create room here https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/api/rooms-resource#create-room. So are the docs here wrong I guess? EDIT: Oh its the return params. That is wholy unhelpful. Any idea why these are not supported?

Comment: It is just not a feature of Twilio Video to set a duration or end time for a room. Those properties are readonly and filled in once a room is complete. You can [complete a room yourself by updating its status to "completed" using the REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/api/rooms-resource#post-instance).